# Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. when deploying on digitalocean with apache2

Tags: reactjs, apache, ubuntu, django-rest-framework, digital-ocean

i have been trying to deploy my react django app on digitalocean the past 5 days and it's not working. i have used this guid https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04 to deploy it but i'm getting an error 403 "Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at 161.35.20.119 Port 80"

and i have logged the apache error and i got this

```
[Fri Mar 26 12:58:39.849945 2021] [core:notice] [pid 2948:tid 140423263165504] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 26 13:01:33.011075 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2948:tid 140423263165504] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 26 13:01:33.227907 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15470:tid 139825591204928] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 26 13:01:33.228180 2021] [core:notice] [pid 15470:tid 139825591204928] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 26 13:14:21.257934 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15470:tid 139825591204928] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Mar 26 13:14:21.314783 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15470:tid 139825591204928] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 26 13:14:21.314810 2021] [core:notice] [pid 15470:tid 139825591204928] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 26 16:00:41.389644 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15470:tid 139825591204928] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 26 16:00:41.625263 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 29582:tid 140329193987136] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 26 16:00:41.625446 2021] [core:notice] [pid 29582:tid 140329193987136] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 26 16:00:49.491113 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29585:tid 140329173669632] [client 84.215.102.211:50612] Attempt to invoke directory as WSGI application: /var/www/html/SamfunnetiBergen/SamfunnetiBergen/
[Fri Mar 26 16:00:49.604457 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29585:tid 140329165276928] [client 84.215.102.211:50612] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/html/SamfunnetiBergen/SamfunnetiBergen/favicon.ico, referer: http://161.35.20.119/
[Fri Mar 26 16:06:16.893930 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29584:tid 140329173669632] [client 84.215.102.211:50730] Attempt to invoke directory as WSGI application: /var/www/html/SamfunnetiBergen/SamfunnetiBergen/
[Fri Mar 26 16:06:47.515371 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29585:tid 140329140098816] [client 84.215.102.211:50745] Attempt to invoke directory as WSGI application: /var/www/html/SamfunnetiBergen/SamfunnetiBergen/
[Fri Mar 26 16:06:48.282807 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29585:tid 140329063806720] [client 84.215.102.211:50745] Attempt to invoke directory as WSGI application: /var/www/html/SamfunnetiBergen/SamfunnetiBergen/
[Fri Mar 26 16:06:48.687099 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29585:tid 140329055414016] [client 84.215.102.211:50745] Attempt to invoke directory as WSGI application: /var/www/html/SamfunnetiBergen/SamfunnetiBergen/
```

so please if anyone can help since i should have delivered this project to my student organisation the last week

Comment: Have you seen this DO answer https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/forbidden-you-don-t-have-permissions-to-access-on-this-server ?

Comment: yea i did that and it didn't work! :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a message in logs:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Check this [help](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/apache-configuration-error-ah00558-could-not-reliably-determine-the-server-s-fully-qualified-domain-name)

Comment: do u know how to fix this? i don't have a domain name yet

Comment: if you want access deployed site then domain name or ip address is needed

Comment: If 161.35.20.119 is your ip address you can use it instead of domain

Comment: yea i added this `<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>

ServerName 161.35.20.119` on `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and still not workin :
(